# How to call oracle stored procedure at PHP using ODBC

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, odbc

I am trying to call an Oracle stored procedure at a PHP website using ODBC.
I have a table named "employees". I want to see the total employee number at the website. Below I am describing the function, procedure and pl/sql to run normally from sql.

**FUNCTION:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_totalEmployees 
RETURN number IS
t_emp number;
BEGIN
        select count(*) INTO t_emp from employees;
    RETURN t_emp;
END;
```

This function will count all entry at employees table. Then store the value at

*t_emp*

**PROCEDURE:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pro_totalEmployees(totalEmployees OUT number) 
IS
BEGIN
    totalEmployees := func_totalEmployees;

END;
```

This procedure will run our function and output one value using *totalEmployees* variable.

**PL/SQL:**

```
DECLARE
see_totalEmployees number;
BEGIN
    pro_totalEmployees(see_totalEmployees);
        dbms_output.put_line('Total Employees you have: ' || see_totalEmployees);
END;
```

Now the execution part. This is just simple pl/sql query which output the total number of employees from our procedure using variable *see_totalEmployees*

That's it!

So at sql, I got the output: **Total Employees you have: 107**

**NOW MY QUESTION:**

How can I store this 107 into a PHP variable using ODBC?

Please Help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this,

```
    <?php
    $Tot_emp = 0;

    // Create connection to db
    $conn = odbc_connect('db_name','user_name','password') or die;

    // Call your procedure
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");

    // Bind the output parameter
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $Tot_emp, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);    

    // call the stored procedure
    $stmt->execute();        

    // $message is now populated with the output value
    print "$Tot_emp\n";
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am using ODBC for establishing connection to database. As I don't know much, can I use oci in middle of the program? please advise. :)